# Equations of 1st order but not of 1st degree.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Topic : equations solvable for p

Q: $(1-y^2+\frac{y^4}{x^2})p^2-\frac{2y}{x}p+\frac{y^2}{x^2}=0$

There is no $\frac{dy}{dx}$ into the equation (if it was, then it has to be replaced by 'p')

Now solving the quadratic equation in p

Using quadratic formula

$\frac{\frac{2y}{x}\pm\frac{4y^2}{x^2}-4(1-y^2+\frac{y^4}{x^2})\frac{y^2}{x^2})}{2(1-y^2+\frac{y^4}{x^2}}$

[image: added it because i'm unable to type whole expression correctly]

---

How to solve this further